# Dash plotly default figure

Tags: plotly-dash

New to Dash-plotly user here.
I am trying to draw a bunch of images based on a user choice picked from dropdown. Let us say the synthetic data is like this.

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output,callback
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

for i in range(10):
    if i == 0:
        X = np.full((100,28, 28), i/10)
        y = np.full((100,),i)
    else:
        tempx = np.full((100,28, 28), i/10)
        tempy = np.full((100,),i)
        X = np.r_[X,tempx]
        y = np.r_[y,tempy]
```

So y is a numpy array of 1000 elements with 0 to 9 each appearing 100 times. Every element of x is y/10 appearing in a 28x28 array.

My objective is to plot random images from X for a user selected value of y from a dropdown. Here's my code.

```
app = Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Dropdown([i for i in range(10)],
                 '0',
                 id='my_dropdown2'),
    
    html.Div(dcc.Graph(id='my_picbox'))
])


@callback(
    Output(component_id='my_picbox', component_property='figure'),
    Input(component_id='my_dropdown2', component_property='value')
)

def update_plot(digit):
    
    x_copy = np.copy(X)
    y_copy= np.copy(y)
    
    lbl_idx = np.random.choice(np.where(y_copy==0)[0], 10)
    fig = px.imshow(X[lbl_idx, :, :],
                    binary_string=False,
                    facet_col=0,
                    facet_col_wrap=10,
                    color_continuous_scale='rdylgn')
    
    if digit:
        lbl_filter = digit
    
        lbl_idx = np.random.choice(np.where(y_copy==lbl_filter)[0], 10)
        
        fig = px.imshow(X[lbl_idx, :, :],
                    binary_string=False,
                    zmin=0,
                    zmax=1,
                    facet_col=0,
                    facet_col_wrap=10,
                    color_continuous_scale='rdylgn')
        fig.update_layout()
    
    return fig


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(mode = 'jupyterlab')
```

On running the plot I expect a default plot of 10 images for 0. This should happen because of the first fig = px.imshow() call, when the selected digit is none. Instead it plots an empty figure
[image]

However, if I select a value from the dropdown, it builds a plot as expected.

[image]

How can I get the default plot working ?

Comment: Does changing the dropdown default value from string to int do the trick ?